# Does anyone know this embroidery font?

Tags: fonts, script, embroidery

[![enter ima[image]

Please and thank you!
I'm attempting to match this script embroidery font????

Comment: Have a look through [these calligraphy fonts](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=601&text=La+Stacey+Kyle) available on Dafont. Note that there are literally thousands of these fonts to check through, and auto font ID sites don't work well with these kind of script fonts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its Skin Deep BB by Blambot. There is also a swashes version, Skin Deep Swashes BB, which may be what you need for the "L". It's not free, sorry. I found the font available for sale on the myfonts-dot-com site. I'm sure it's available on many sites. Best of luck. : )